# Will a DECT phone wireless signal interfere with a WiFi access point signal?

Tags: wireless-networking

Will a DECT phone / DECT base / DECT repeater interfere with the signal to/from a Wi-Fi access point?

In a couple of locations there are going to be Wi-Fi access points (Ubiquity UAP Pros) near to either DECT phone bases, DECT phones or repeaters. (All telephony gear is Yealkink w56 range.)

Comment: There are some 2.4 GHz cordless phones that will cause interference. I don't believe those are as common these days.

Comment: @InterLinked True, but most Yealink cordless phones are DECT SIP devices, and the W series (60, 56, 52, and 41) are all purely DECT devices.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No, if they are operating correctly DECT and WiFi shouldn't interfere with each other.

DECT operates in the 1900Mhz frequency range, specifically 1880-1930Mhz (in some regions up to 1980Mhz). Your Yealink W-series Wireless phones fall in this category.

Most WiFi operates in the 2.4Ghz (802.11b/g/n) or 5GHz (802.11a/h/j/n/ac/ax) frequency ranges. Your AP's fall in this category.

There are also some limited use cases for WiFi in following frequency ranges: 3.65 Ghz (802.11y), 4.9 GHz (802.11j), 5.9 GHz (802.11p), 60 GHz (802.11ad/ay), and 900 MHz (802.11ah), but to my knowledge your Ubiquity UAP Pro AP's do not support any of these rarely used frequencies.

Since the operating frequency of these devices are significantly separated, they should not interfere with each other, assuming they are functioning properly.

Comment: Thanks i just checked the spec for the DECT repeater and it opperates in the EU / UK at 1880 MHz to 1900 MHz

Answer (score 4):

If the distance is short enough then anything can interfere with everything. Bandpass filters only have so much damping, even an out-of-band DECT signal can overdrive a reveiver and make it deaf for the in-band WiFi signal, and vice versa.

The frequency separation and spatial separation must work together.

That being said, my own DECT base station and dual band WiFi access point are only 1/2 meter apart, and they both seem to work well enough. YMMV.

Comment: Part of "working properly" is not emitting such massive power levels that they cause interference even if very close.  Pretty sure this is regulated.  Also that they don't cook anything you leave near them :P

Comment: Our test bench Yealink W60P DECT base literally sits on top of a Meraki MR42 AP (it is set on top of it) and neither one interferes with the other.