# Placing Wireless-AP and DECT VoIP Base Station side by side - will they disturb each other?

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-access-point, signal-strength, power-over-ethernet

I need to place a `wireless access point` and a `DECT VoIP base station` into an office. Now there is a perfect location in the center of the room, which is why I am thinking about to assemble both devices directly beside each other at this position.

Will they disturb each other? Are there any disadvantages to be expected when assembling a wireless AP and a DECT base directly beside each other?

**Edit:** Seems to be the same question like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/1315667/will-a-dect-phone-wireless-signal-interfere-with-a-wifi-access-point-signal/1315703#1315703).

Comment: There’s even Wi-Fi routers with a DECT base station built-in. Works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is no.

They are on different non-conflicting frequencies,
and they will not interfere with one another.

"DECT operates in the 1880–1900 MHz band and defines ten frequency channels from 1881.792 MHz to 1897.344 MHz with a band gap of 1728 kHz." ~ Wikipedia

802.11 networks operate in two bands depending on the router and internal radios. The 2.4ghz band and 5.8ghz band respectively.

You should be fine installing them in the same location.